# Using lists from another script

Tags: list, applescript

In applescript can you use a list from another script
eg have in one script

```
set example to {"A","B"}
```

And in another have

```
choose from list example
```

Can this be used in the editor or does it need to be a app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/tmp/a.scpt`:

```
property example : {"A", "B"}
```

Another script:

```
set s to (load script "/tmp/a.scpt")
example of s -- {"A", "B"}
```

Comment: getting error "Can’t make \"/Documents/applescript/tests/lists.scpt\" into type file." number -1700

Comment: You have to specify the path like `"/Users/username/Documents/applescript/tests/lists.scpt"`.